# Сделала тестовую игру в Tkinter, не понимаю, как сделать начало игры по нажатию кнопки старт

Tags: python, tkinter, button

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, canvas, paddle, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.paddle = paddle
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 25, 25, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)
        starts = [-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3]
        random.shuffle(starts)
        self.x = starts[0]
        self.y = -3
        self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.hit_bottom = False

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[1] <= 0:
            self.y = 3
        if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height:
            self.hit_bottom == True
        if self.hit_paddle(pos) == True:
            self.y = -3
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 3
        if pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = -3
            
    def hit_paddle(self, pos):
        paddle_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle.id)
        if pos[2] >= paddle_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle_pos[2]:
            if pos[3] >= paddle_pos[1] and pos[3] <= paddle_pos[3]:
                return True

            return False

class Paddle:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 10, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 200, 300)
        self.x = 0
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>', self.turn_left)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>', self.turn_right)

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, 0)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 0
        elif pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = 0

    def turn_left(self, evt):
        self.x = -3

    def turn_right(self, evt):
        self.x = 3
        
tk = Tk()
tk.title('Игра')
tk.resizable(0, 0)
tk.wm_attributes('-topmost', 1)

canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=400, bd=0,
                highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
tk.update()

paddle = Paddle(canvas, 'blue')
ball = Ball(canvas, paddle, 'red')

while 1:

    if ball.hit_bottom == False:
        ball.draw()
        paddle.draw()
    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так:
P.S сделал по простому дальше сами думайте как оформить Меню :)

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, canvas, paddle, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.paddle = paddle
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 25, 25, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)
        starts = [-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3]
        random.shuffle(starts)
        self.x = starts[0]
        self.y = -3
        self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.hit_bottom = False

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[1] <= 0:
            self.y = 3
        if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height:
            self.hit_bottom == True
        if self.hit_paddle(pos) == True:
            self.y = -3
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 3
        if pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = -3
            
    def hit_paddle(self, pos):
        paddle_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle.id)
        if pos[2] >= paddle_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle_pos[2]:
            if pos[3] >= paddle_pos[1] and pos[3] <= paddle_pos[3]:
                return True

            return False

class Paddle:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 10, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 200, 300)
        self.x = 0
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>', self.turn_left)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>', self.turn_right)

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, 0)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 0
        elif pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = 0

    def turn_left(self, evt):
        self.x = -3

    def turn_right(self, evt):
        self.x = 3

def start():
    start_win.destroy()
start_win = Tk()
start_win.title('Menu')
start_win.geometry('500x400')
start = Button(start_win, text='Start Game', command=start)
start.place(x=210, y=150)
start_win.mainloop()

tk = Tk()
tk.title('Игра')
tk.resizable(0, 0)
tk.wm_attributes('-topmost', 1)

canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=400, bd=0,
                highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
tk.update()

paddle = Paddle(canvas, 'blue')
ball = Ball(canvas, paddle, 'red')

while 1:

    if ball.hit_bottom == False:
        ball.draw()
        paddle.draw()
    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)
tk.mainloop()
```